# form validation on special character with i18n

Tags: javascript, validation, regular-language

I am trying to validate a input that can not contain ant special character.

But I want it supports i18n, which means it can not contain any special character in different language.(!@#$%^&*()_+！@#￥%……&*（）——+  and so on),

Is it possible to validate it with a regular expression?

Comment: Do you mean "can someone write a regular expression for me"?

Comment: Yes it is. So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @ḞḹáḿíṅḡⱫỏḿƀíé yes, if you may.